# Describe or explaining the Engineering occupation

Tags: usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are  the words “engineering” or “engineer” translated in Cantonese?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1113/how-are-the-words-engineering-or-engineer-translated-in-cantonese)

I love what I do and my family has no idea what I really do. I can explain it in English, but I have a hard time thinking of a way to explain it in Chinese. I am a computer engineer (and student) and I thought just saying "computer engineer" in chinese would make sense, i.e, 电脑工程师. I feel like I have to explain the engineering portion. I presume computers make sense to my native chinese people, but engineering isnt.

What I thought up was saying "I build computers" but its so inaccurate its almost offensive to myself.

Engineering in english is someone who designs and builds a structure which will "fix" or improve a certain way of performing something, i.e improving a systems using whatever field of focus (mechanical, electrical, computer, etc) to improve how things are done. e.g, Cellphones were engineered to remove people from a land-line (very crude example), or cars moved people away from horse carriages.

good reference is from [Engineering: Wiki](http://Engineering%20is%20the%20discipline,%20art,%20skill%20and%20profession%20of%20acquiring%20and%20applying%20scientific,%20mathematical,%20economic,%20social,%20and%20practical%20knowledge,%20in%20order%20to%20design%20and%20build%20structures,%20machines,%20devices,%20systems,%20materials%20and%20processes.) :

> Engineering is the discipline, art, skill and profession of acquiring
>   and applying scientific, mathematical, economic, social, and practical
>   knowledge, in order to design and build structures, machines, devices,
>   systems, materials and processes.

Comment: What is your actual question? I cannot understand what you're asking... It seems a translation request but it looks like a dupe of the previous one. If you want to discuss about it, you can ping me in chat (use @ and then my user name).

Comment: I closed your question because to me it seems you're asking the same thing, only with a different wording. If you want to discuss about it, feel free to post a question in [meta](http://meta.chinese.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In general, people know what "工程师" means. 
If you say "computer engineer", people will assume you are doing some programming work. If you can be more specific about what kind of engineering? It will explain everything.

For instance, computer hardware engineer, software engineer,network engineer and so on...